# Joining two Queries in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the total sum of likes a user has on his posts in SQL. Essentially I have the following table design:

Table Content :

1. content_id
2. poster_id

Table Likes :

1. content_id
2. upvoteOrDownVote
3. liker_id

So essentially what I need to do is get all of the `content_id` from the `Content` table, where `poster_id == user` and then for each of those `content_id` I need to get all likes from the `Likes` table. It's easy to do these queries separately, but I'm not sure how to combine it into one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join the two tables and use `COUNT(*)` to count the selected rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS likes
FROM Likes AS l
JOIN Content AS c ON l.content_id = c.content_id
WHERE c.poster_id = user
AND l.upvoteOrDownVote = 'upvote'
```